# Is there a way to share only ONE desktop in Mavericks?

Tags: macos, display, remote-desktop, desktop

I've recently started to work with multi-desktops and multi-screens environment. What I'm trying to do is:

1. Working on my Mavericks (MBA) as the main computer with Desktop #1 in front.
2. Use an external computer (I'm using Linux-Ubuntu but I don't mind to use Windows if needed) as my external display to Desktop #2. This will be view-only.

This way I can extend my Mac view to a 2nd display that is connected to a 2nd computer and when I need it - I can use it as an external view to desktop #2.

Now, I *know* I can connect the external monitor directly to my Mac. I am trying to avoid it because this is a temporary work area that I'm using and this monitor must stay connected to that Ubuntu/Windows workstation; I just want to leverage the LAN to share Desktop #2 (Only) with that external station/monitor.

NVC on Mac will not let me see a specific desktop only; the VNC built-in solution basically mirrors whatever I see on my own Mac screen in front of me which is Desktop #1. The simplest way (If I only could find how) is to let a VNC server on my laptop to share desktop #2 only, but any other solution will be appreciated as well!